# Right to left languages in panorama-Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, hebrew

I want to make right to left language(Hebrew) in panorama window(So the scroll will be to left instead of right), how can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the flow direction property of your listboxes, textboxes etc. to right to left. The panorama control itself also has this property.